# Lyx: Numerical bibliography sorted by appearance

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using Lyx 2.0, everything works fine but I'm in trouble with the bibliography. I want to have the citations in order by appearance in the text.

For example:

```
Jbjb[1] jbibihz[2].

Library:
[1] Author1
[2] Author 2
```

But in the moment, my library is in an alphabetic order and in the text the numbers are like this:

```
Dssfg[3]oihdovn[1]jbiub[2].
```

I'm using `natbib` and the style `unsrt`. But `unsrt` doesn't alter the problem.

My source code is as follows, maybe there is any mistake I didn't find:

```
%% LyX 2.0.6 created this file. For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[twoside,ngerman,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=4.5cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=3.5cm,rmargin=5cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1.5cm,footskip=1.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[dot]{bibtopic}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\AtBeginDocument{
\def\labelitemii{\(\circ\)}
\def\labelitemiii{\(\cdot\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
afegbab\cite{TaeWanKim.2011}zglivf\cite{KamilaKoichumanova.2013}egadsvafdb\cite{R.R.Davda.2005}\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{btSect}{C:/literatur2}
\btPrintCited
\end{btSect}

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated!!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Try loading `\bibliographystyle{un­srt­nat}` *after* you load `natbib`. Note that I've used `unsrtnat`, not `unsrt`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to load unsrtnat after natbib but I have still the same problem. I got an option clash if I put "natbib numeric" in document -> settings -> bibliography -> bibliographystyle. With "default(numerical)" it is working but still the same problem.:(

Comment: nobody has any idea?? :(

Comment: Can you supply a screen shot of how you input your code? Also, please use one of the default LyX bibliography databases rather than `literatur2`. I'm able to generate the appropriate `unsrtnat` by loading [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) from Document > Settings... > Bibliography > Natbib (Numerical) (using `bibtex`) and adding `PassOptionsToPackage{sort&compress}{natbib}` to the Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere in your file, where the bibliography should appear in the final document, there is a gray rectangle with the words "Generated BibTeX bibliography" (or something similar). Click there. In the opened window, go to the popup menu corresponding to bib styles and choose `unsrt`. Accept and generate a new document.

[LyX bibliography sorting order is not automatic? Help!](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2492)

I used `unsrtnat`.

Answer (score 2):

In LyX version 2.3.5.2 use the following setting:

Document->Setting->Bibliography
[image]

Comment: This "answer" could use more information. For example how a particular setting would match the desired result or a screenshot of output.